# Im trying to figure out if my casinos would generate loss or win. Need Help!

Tags: probability

So basically I already figured out the percentage for winning at my (imaginary) casinos.

There are 3 casinos in total:

One with 0.137% chance of winning

One with 0.015% chance of winning and

One with 0.00169% chance of winning.

You pay 1 Dollar for one try. 
Payout for winning is 576 Dollars.

Am i gonna stay in posives (if yes how much left over) or am i gonna run into negatives (if yes how much loss) for each casino.

An equation on how to do this would also be much appreciated!

Thank you!!

Comment: There are $3$ what?  Games?  All three games have the same payout?  Obviously everyone would play the game with the highest chance of winning.

Comment: yes but this is all theoretically. just would like know how to do this problem and the answer for each casino with corresponding equation.

Comment: Well...take the game with the highest probability. That one has an expected payout of $.00137\times 576\approx .79$  so, you should charge about $79$ cents.  As you are charging $100$ cents you are looking quite secure.